# How to get attributes from the output in the graphical modeler of QGIS

Tags: fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

I'd like to know how to get attributes (to insert it into a specific string) from the output of an algorithm which is present in a flow of the graphical modeler of QGIS. Possibly, i don't want to extract/create this output from the algorithm (green rectangle), i don't want to get this attribute from an input and i don't want to use attributes of a layer in the TOC.
I tried to use these strings but without good results:

10 - attribute(get_feature_by_id ('layer_OUTPUT',1), 'field'))

10 - attribute(get_feature_by_id (@layer_OUTPUT,1), 'field'))

Any suggestions?